# How can I add a transparent to black gradient over a div / image?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have some flex boxes that contain an image and text.

```
.bItem {
    display: flex;
    display: block;
    justify-content: flex-end;   
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 9px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 9px;
    padding: 18px;  
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="box">
 <a class="bItem" href="/about/" style="background-image:url(/images/one.jpg);" >
  <div class="bText white">
    <h3>TITLE</h3>
    Additional text here.</div>
  </a>
 </div>
```

I assumed something like this, attached to `.bItem` would work:

```
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
```

Is there a way I can attach it to `.bItem`, preferably without having to add another class?

The issue I am having is that the text is hard to read, with the white text, and a gradient to black at the bottom would help make it more legible.

Comment: Where do you expect the background gradient to display relative to the background image?

Comment: It would be good to have the gradient over the image. I have tried removing the cover, no good unfortunately.

Comment: roger that. gave you a solution. that what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't use the gradient and background image at the same time on the same element, since both are a `background-image`. But you can assign the gradient to a pseudo element of `.bItem`, so you won't have to include an additional element for it. Also, you can just use `transparent` and `black` instead of `rgba()`

```css
.bItem {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 9px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 9px;
  padding: 18px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url(http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png);
}

.bItem:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, black 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a class="bItem" href="/about/">
    <div class="bText white">
      <h3>TITLE</h3> Additional text here.</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Works a dream. Many thanks for your help. Qq: Is `black` etc safe to use, or should you always refer to `#000` ?

Comment: @davv awesome, no problem. `black` and `#000` and `#000000` are all the same thing, use whichever one makes you happiest :)

Comment: Hey Michael. Is there any way I can tighten up the gradient so it only goes to black from transparent near enough right at the bottom of the div? It is causing the images (which are already b&w to look too dark). Many thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Do not apply the gradient to the anchor tag.  Create another class to apply the linear gradient to the background container with one line as such:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%), url(/images/one.jpg);
```

This will allow the gradient to be applied only to the background image while allowing the text to remain unaffected.  You may then style the text and anchor tags independently.

Comment: Much better over having to work against z-index with sudo-elements

Answer (score 0):

An anchor  tag is inline.  You can only apply a background to a block.  So you can change the  display type to "block."  This might cause other problems, but start there.

Comment: I do already have a block in my css class. Sorry, I didn't include it on here first off, but it was there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for but here is how you make a gradient on text.

```
 h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> if you want linear gradient on image you can add background color to class of div and decrease image opacity.

```
<div class="col">         \\set background color for col class in
     <img src="" alt="">  \\now set opacity for img in css
</div>
```